# Low performance with linq and INTERSECT/EXCEPT in small collections

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq

how are you?

I know there are plenty of questions and answers about it, but my case is quite particular because I dont have large arrays to intersect. I am implementing a search method that receives a search object and, using linq, searchs into the DB (I am using EF 6 with code first).

- So, I have the following entities in the DB with these columns:

  -*User*: userId (int), name (string).

  -*UserFeatures*: userId (int), featuresId (short).

  -*Features*: featuresId (short), description (string).
- My search object is like this:

  {
    "name":"Friedrich Wilhelm",
    "features": [1,2,3,4]
  }
- My linq query is like this (the idea is to get all the users that match the features the logged user is looking for).

  context.User.Where(u => 
  userToSearch.features.Except(u.UserFeatures.Select(uf => 
  uf.featuresId))).Any()==false).toListAsync();

This works fine, but it takes 30 seconds aprox. I have 30k users in the DB but each user has around 4 and 5 features each.

I already try using hashset, but as the feature collections are not big, makes no difference. The problem is maybe that I have 30k users with 5 features each. So that means about 150k iterations.

Do you have any idea how i can improve this? In the query I have also another conditions. If I delete the one with the features, the query is much faster (around 4 seconds to run. I am implementing also Paginations -Take, skip, etc.).

Comment: Can you show the Actual Execution Plan of that query in the SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be faster to use a `join` and `group by` like this:

```
int numberOfFeatures = userToSearch.features.Count();
var userIds = from u in context.Users
              from uf in u.UserFeatures
              where userToSearch.features.Contains(uf.featuresId)
              group u by u.userId into g
              where g.Count() == numberOfFeatures 
              select u.Key;
```

Alternatively if you want the user objects

```
var users = ...
            select u.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It worked great! This actually improve the performance more than I expected: less than a second to run! Thanks a lot, Aducci.

Comment: Wonderful! I was very concerned about the performance of my query.

Answer (score 1):

That query, and a similar one, worked fine for me. As for query forms, the two below are the only ones that come to mind, unless you have the linking entity in your model.  Anyway take a look at this repro, and see if it behaves differently for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{

    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Feature> Feaures { get; } = new HashSet<Feature>();
    }
    public class Feature
    {
        public int FeatureId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; } = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }



    class Program
    {      

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            if (true)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());
                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    var features = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => new Feature() { Description = $"Feature{i}" }).ToList();

                    var users = Enumerable.Range(1, 30000).Select(i => new User() { Name = $"User{i}" }).ToList();
                    var rand = new Random();
                    foreach (var u in users)
                    {
                        var featureCount = rand.Next(4, 5);
                        for (int i = 0; i < featureCount; i++)
                        {
                            u.Feaures.Add(features[rand.Next(0, features.Count - 1)]);
                        }
                    }

                    db.Users.AddRange(users);
                    db.Features.AddRange(features);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            List<int> requestedFeatureIds;
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Feaures.Count() == 4).AsEnumerable().Last() ;
                requestedFeatureIds = user.Feaures.Select(f => f.FeatureId).ToList();
            }

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                //context.User.Where(u => userToSearch.features.Except(u.UserFeatures.Select(uf => uf.featuresId))).Any()==false).toListAsync();
                var q = db.Users.Where(u => requestedFeatureIds.Except(u.Feaures.Select(uf => uf.FeatureId)).Any() == false);

                var results = q.ToList();

                var q2 = from u in db.Users
                         where requestedFeatureIds.Intersect(u.Feaures.Select(f => f.FeatureId)).Count() == requestedFeatureIds.Count
                         select u;

                var results2 = q2.ToList();


            }


            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

outputs (in relevant part)

```
    Opened connection at 9/7/2017 11:32:12 AM -05:00

    SELECT
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId],
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 0 = (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  (SELECT
                [UnionAll3].[C1] AS [C1]
                FROM  (SELECT
                    3 AS [C1]
                    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                    7 AS [C1]
                    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                    9 AS [C1]
                    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                    17 AS [C1]
                    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]) AS [UnionAll3]
            EXCEPT
                SELECT
                [Extent2].[Feature_FeatureId] AS [Feature_FeatureId]
                FROM [dbo].[UserFeatures] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[User_UserId]) AS [Except1]
        )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)


    -- Executing at 9/7/2017 11:32:12 AM -05:00

    -- Completed in 94 ms with result: SqlDataReader



    Closed connection at 9/7/2017 11:32:12 AM -05:00

    Opened connection at 9/7/2017 11:32:12 AM -05:00

    SELECT
        [Project7].[UserId] AS [UserId],
        [Project7].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId],
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
            (SELECT
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM  (SELECT
                    [UnionAll3].[C1] AS [C1]
                    FROM  (SELECT
                        3 AS [C1]
                        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT
                        7 AS [C1]
                        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT
                        9 AS [C1]
                        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT
                        17 AS [C1]
                        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]) AS [UnionAll3]
                INTERSECT
                    SELECT
                    [Extent2].[Feature_FeatureId] AS [Feature_FeatureId]
                    FROM [dbo].[UserFeatures] AS [Extent2]
                    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[User_UserId]) AS [Intersect1]) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Project7]
        WHERE [Project7].[C1] = @p__linq__0


    -- p__linq__0: '4' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

    -- Executing at 9/7/2017 11:32:12 AM -05:00

    -- Completed in 206 ms with result: SqlDataReader



    Closed connection at 9/7/2017 11:32:13 AM -05:00

Hit any key to exit
```